# DeleteAttachment method in List web service for sharepoint 2010 is with "Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException" error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a document library named "`Registrant`" and inside the library registrants are uploading documents to THEIR OWN Folder say "`REGISTRANT1_GUIDofRegistrant1`"

Currently the situation is "http://registry.example.com/CRMDocuments/contact/"

where "`CRMDocuments`" is the folder inside. I have multiple document libraries like Registrant(contact is the name appears in the URL because "`Registrant`" is the display name).

I have a web portal in which a registrant can register and login through:

"http://registry.example.com/register.aspx"

After registration, they can upload documents to share point and that will be listed in the web portal and there is provision to delete the documents if they want.

At the initial upload system will be creating a folder inside the "Registrant" document library in the format "`REGISTRANT1_GUIDofRegistrant1`" and all the files will be stored inside this folder.

I am using share point 2010 web services to create folder and upload documents, get list of items from the specific folder and DELETE any attachment inside the folder.

Web service references in MSDN are:

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.deleteattachment%28v=office.14%29.aspx

I am creating a "SERVICE REFERENCE" for these web services for Create folder, upload documents and get list of items from the specific folder are working perfectly, but delete is NOT.

I have code reference:

```
    BasicHttpBinding bind = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            BasicHttpSecurity security = new BasicHttpSecurity();
            HttpTransportSecurity http = new HttpTransportSecurity();
            http.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

            security.Transport = http;
            security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            bind.Security = security;

            SharePoint.List.ListsSoapClient client = new SharePoint.List.ListsSoapClient(bind, new EndpointAddress("http://registry.example.com/CRMDocuments/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"));

             NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("UserID", "Password", "Domain");

            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = cred;


client.DeleteAttachment("Registrant", "516", "http://registry.example.com/CRMDocuments/contact/REGISTRANT1_b2ad3754-65a8-e311-befb-60a44cce3a94/sample1_Education.jpg");
```

This is coming up with an error:

```
"Exception of type
'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown"
```

With stack trace:

```
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Registry.SharePoint.List.ListsSoap.DeleteAttachment(DeleteAttachmentRequest request)
   at Registry.SharePoint.List.ListsSoapClient.Registry.SharePoint.List.ListsSoap.DeleteAttachment(DeleteAttachmentRequest request) in c:\Dev\Solution\Lib\Service References\SharePoint.List\Reference.cs:line 2923
   at Registry.SharePoint.List.ListsSoapClient.DeleteAttachment(String listName, String listItemID, String url) in c:\Dev\PSW_Solution\PSWLib\Service References\SharePoint.List\Reference.cs:line 2932
   at Registry.PSWDocumentLocation.DeleteItemInDocumentLibrary(XrmServiceContext x, Entity entity, String sMOSSURL, NetworkCredential cred, String id, String url) in c:\Dev\Solution\Lib\DocumentLocation.cs:line 203
```

Can have some thoughts on this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution

```
string batchId = "Batch123";
string id = "156"; //Document Id (NOT GUID)

                string strBatch = "<Batch OnError='Continue'><Method ID='" + batchId + "' Cmd='Delete'>" +
                           "<Field Name='ID'>" + id + "</Field>" +
                           "<Field Name='FileRef'>" + url + "</Field>" +
                          "</Method></Batch>";

                XDocument elBatch = XDocument.Parse(strBatch);
                XElement res = client.UpdateListItems("registrant", elBatch.Root);
```

This will do the job. I know this is not the actual solution for my problem, but this is definitely a work around.

Vinu